# Call method only once and apply filter to save result in different variables in scala

Tags: scala

```
 temp1 <- Future.sequence(file.map { ref =>
    readFile(ref, config).map { (ref, _) }
  }).map(f => f.filter(parsed => parsed._2.errors.nonEmpty))

  temp2 <- Future.sequence(file.map { ref =>
  readFile(ref, config).map { (ref, _) }
  })
```

I dont want to call readFile method 2 times. How to call it only once and save the output in temp1 and temp2 as per filter.

Comment: Your code starts with `temp1 <-`. No valid Scala program (not even a single isolated Scala expression) can start with `identifier <-`.

Comment: was any of the fairly extensive feedback you received on https://gitter.im/scala/scala about this same question useful...?

Comment: @SethTisue Indeed it was :-)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code correctly you want `temp1` and `temp2` contains similar data, but on `temp2` you additionally call `map(...)` so why cant you create `temp2` first and then set `temp1 = temp2.map(f => f.filter(parsed => parsed._2.errors.nonEmpty))` this way you would call readFile just once. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I was not looking for something similar.. but I figured out by what you said in the comments.. It helped me to resolve another issue. Thanks :-)